# Display of Custom Fields based on conditional if/and according to category/tag choice

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am attempting to create php code that does 1 of 2 things subject to certain crtieria -

1. If a post category is defined as either 'News','Features','Tech' certain custom fields created usin ACF are displayed; or,
2. If a post category is defined as 'Research' and the post has one of the following tags - 'aged care', 'anxiety/stress', 'autism', 'cognitive', 'Dementia', 'Parkinson's', 'sleep' , 'well-being' - other custom fields created usin ACF are displayed.

I have gone completely blank, tried different coding options but can't seem to get it to work. My latest code attempt is:

```
<?php

$hb1 = in_category(array('News','Features','Tech'));
$hb2 =  in_category(array('Research'));
$hb3 = has_tag( array( 'aged care', 'anxiety/stress', 'autism', 'cognitive', 'Dementia', 'Parkinson's', 'sleep' , 'well-being'  ));

?>

<?php 

if (in_category($hb1, $this->post->ID))
{
   the_field('media_outlet', $this->post->ID);
   the_field('media_outlet_url', $this->post->ID);
   the_field('published_date', $this->post->ID)
}
else if (in_category($hb2, $this->post->ID)) && (has_tag ($hb3, $this->post->ID))
{
   the_field('media_outlet', $this->post->ID);
   the_field('published_date', $this->post->ID);
   the_field('country', $this->post->ID)
}

?>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$hb1`, `$hb2` and `$hb3` are boolean variables, therefore

```
if ( in_category($hb1, $this->post->ID) )
```

is always FALSE.

Try the following code:

```
$hb1 = in_category( 
           array('News','Features','Tech'), 
           $this->post->ID 
);
$hb2 = in_category( array('Research'), $this->post->ID );
$hb3 = has_tag( 
         array( 'aged care', 'anxiety/stress', 'autism', 'cognitive', 'Dementia', "Parkinson's", 'sleep' , 'well-being' ), 
         $this->post->ID
);

if ( $hb1 )
{
   the_field('media_outlet',     $this->post->ID);
   the_field('media_outlet_url', $this->post->ID);
   the_field('published_date',   $this->post->ID)
}
else if ( $hb2 && $hb3 )
{
   the_field('media_outlet',   $this->post->ID);
   the_field('published_date', $this->post->ID);
   the_field('country',        $this->post->ID)
}
```

---

Reference:

- [in_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/)
- [has_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/)

Comment: Hi NMR, your suggested worked great on the page I was working on but is breaking when I apply it, albeit slightly tweaked to another and I can't see why. I created a new post here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344849/working-if-and-else-if-php-calling-acf-custom-fields-breaks-on-new-page if you are able to help. Thanks. Best Wishes, Gary